# Cast TResponse to Response class in IRequestPostProcessor

Tags: c#, mediatr

I'm new in C# and I need some help to implement IRequestPostProcessor in mediatr.

I Have a Post Processor Behavior, TResponse is Always a generic Response Class that wrap an other object (Data).
In NullUnauthorizedPropsBehaviour I need to access to Response properties in order to iterate Data properties to get their attributes.

```
public class NullUnauthorizedPropsBehaviour<TRequest, TResponse> : IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse> 
    {
        public Task Process(TRequest request, TResponse response, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            // I need TResponse to be casted to Response class in order to access to its properties

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

My Response class  is a generic:

```
public class Response<T>
    {
        public Response()
        {
        }

        public Response(T data, string message = null)
        {
            Succeeded = true;
            Message = message;
            Data = data;
        }

        public Response(string message)
        {
            Succeeded = false;
            Message = message;
        }

        public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public List<string> Errors { get; set; }
        public T Data { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't know how to do it, please any help?

Comment: thank you for your reply. Yes I tried but Response is Generic also, so I don't how to do it. What I did  `where TResponse : Response` but Response is Generic, What can I put inside it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the `response` parameter to be fully generic - you want it to only be a `Response<>` type.

```
public class NullUnauthorizedPropsBehaviour<TRequest, TResponse> : 
    IRequestPostProcessor<TRequest, TResponse>
{
    public Task Process(TRequest request, Response<TResponse> response, 
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
}
```

The key here is changing the `response` parameter type from `TResponse` to `Response<TResponse>`.

Now `TResponse` represents the data of the `Response` class, rather than the entire response object.

The `response` object (parameter) in the method can now access `Response` level members, like `.Succeeded` and so on.

Comment: I tried this solution but It doesn't work I have this error `System.ArgumentException: Implementation type 'NullUnauthorizedPropsBehaviour`2[StudentBasicInfosQuery,Application.Wrappers.Response`1[Navigators.Application.DTOs.StudentBasicInfosResponse]]' can't be converted to service type 'IRequestPostProcessor`2[Navigators.Application.Features.Students.Queries.GetStudentBasicInfos.StudentBasicInfosQuery,Application.Wrappers.Response`1[Navigators.Application.DTOs.StudentBasicInfosResponse]]`

Comment: You need to change your interface to accommodate the class changes.